# Pass number of site from one list to another: Need assistance

Tags: javascript, caml-query

I need to pass from one site to another number of site and shiow this record on the View. If I passing record by ID it's all work great, but when I pass by caml Query nothing happening. I tried many times and use u2u to, but when I use camlQuery nothing showing, here is my code:

```
     <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script> 
<script>
var abc = function()
{
getSelectedItems().then(function(items){
var myItems = '';
var i;
document.getElementById("p1").innerHTML="";
for (i in items){
    myItems = items[i].get_id();
    site = items[i].get_item("SITE");
    document.getElementById("p1").innerHTML += items[i].get_id() +" "+ site +" "+ items[i].get_item("Title")+" "+ items[i].get_item("kierownik")+" "+ items[i].get_item("konsultant")+"<br />";
   // window.location.href = window.location.pathname + window.location.search + window.location.hash;
    var targetListItem;
    updateListItem(myItems,site);
    }
}
    )
}

function updateListItem(j,site) {
    var siteUrl = '/sites/MCUW-IT/kostka-pilotaze/restauracje-pilotaże/';
    var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext(siteUrl);
    var oList = clientContext.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle('Testowa Lista');
    // var collListItem = oList.getItemById(j);

    var queryString ="<View><Query><Where><Contains><FieldRef Name="Connect" /><Value Type="LookupMulti">5</Value></Contains></Where></Query></View>";
        var query = new SP.CamlQuery();
        query.set_viewXml(queryString);
        collListItem = oList.getItems(query);


    collListItem.set_item('Poka_x017c_WWidoku', 'Tak');
    collListItem.update();
    clientContext.load(collListItem);

    clientContext.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQuerySucceeded), Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQueryFailed));
}

function onQuerySucceeded() {

    alert('Item updated!');
}

function onQueryFailed(sender, args) {

    alert('Request failed. ' + args.get_message() + '\n' + args.get_stackTrace());
}


function getSelectedItems()
{
    var dfd = $.Deferred(function () {
       var context = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
       var listId = SP.ListOperation.Selection.getSelectedList(); //get selected list Id
       var selectedItemIds = SP.ListOperation.Selection.getSelectedItems(context); //get selected objects
       var list = context.get_web().get_lists().getById(listId);
       var listItems = [];
       for (idx in selectedItemIds)
       {
          var item = list.getItemById(parseInt(selectedItemIds[idx].id));
          listItems.push(item);
          context.load(item);
       }
       context.executeQueryAsync(
         function() {
            dfd.resolve(listItems);
         },
         function (sender, args) {
               dfd.reject(args.get_message());
         }
       ); 
    });
    return dfd.promise();   
}
</script>

<input id="123" onclick="abc();" type="button" value="Pokaż rekordy"/>
<div>
   <p id="p1">​​<br/></p>
</div>
```

Please help me. I must pass number of site, not id number because I need to find if column connect has got a column with has got mamy number of sites.

**EDITED**

I tried this bottom code with enumerator, but button still don't fire:

```
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script> 
<script>
var abc = function()
{
getSelectedItems().then(function(items){
var myItems = '';
var i;
document.getElementById("p1").innerHTML="";
for (i in items){
    myItems = items[i].get_id();
    site = items[i].get_item("SITE");
    document.getElementById("p1").innerHTML += items[i].get_id() +" "+ site +" "+ items[i].get_item("Title")+" "+ items[i].get_item("kierownik")+" "+ items[i].get_item("konsultant")+"<br />";
   // window.location.href = window.location.pathname + window.location.search + window.location.hash;
    var targetListItem;
    updateListItem(myItems,site);
    }
}
    )
}

function updateListItem(j,site) {
    var siteUrl = '/sites/MCUW-IT/kostka-pilotaze/restauracje-pilotaże/';
    var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext(siteUrl);
    var oList = clientContext.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle('Testowa Lista');
    // var collListItem = oList.getItemById(j);

    var queryString ="<View><Query><Where><Contains><FieldRef Name="Connect" /><Value Type="LookupMulti">5</Value></Contains></Where></Query></View>";
        var query = new SP.CamlQuery();
        query.set_viewXml(queryString);
        collListItem = oList.getItems(query);

    clientContext.load(collListItem, 'Include(Connect)');
    collListItem.set_item('Poka_x017c_WWidoku', 'Tak');
    collListItem.update();


    clientContext.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQuerySucceeded), Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQueryFailed));
}

function onQuerySucceeded() {

 var listEnumerator = listItems.getEnumerator();
            while (listEnumerator.moveNext()) {

                // get the current list item.
                var listItem = listEnumerator.get_current();

                // get the field value.
                var fieldValue = listItem.get_item('Connect');


                alert('Item updated!'+fieldValue);

    }
}

function onQueryFailed(sender, args) {

    alert('Request failed. ' + args.get_message() + '\n' + args.get_stackTrace());
}


function getSelectedItems()
{
    var dfd = $.Deferred(function () {
       var context = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
       var listId = SP.ListOperation.Selection.getSelectedList(); //get selected list Id
       var selectedItemIds = SP.ListOperation.Selection.getSelectedItems(context); //get selected objects
       var list = context.get_web().get_lists().getById(listId);
       var listItems = [];
       for (idx in selectedItemIds)
       {
          var item = list.getItemById(parseInt(selectedItemIds[idx].id));
          listItems.push(item);
          context.load(item);
       }
       context.executeQueryAsync(
         function() {
            dfd.resolve(listItems);
         },
         function (sender, args) {
               dfd.reject(args.get_message());
         }
       ); 
    });
    return dfd.promise();   
}
</script>

<input id="123" onclick="abc();" type="button" value="Pokaż rekordy"/>
<div>
   <p id="p1">​​<br/></p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
oList.getItems(query);
```

will return item collection. You need to explicitly load and execute this collection and then iterate through all item one by one to achieve.

Below code for your reference:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script> 
<script>
var abc = function()
{
getSelectedItems().then(function(items){
var myItems = '';
var i;
document.getElementById("p1").innerHTML="";
for (i in items){
    myItems = items[i].get_id();
    document.getElementById("p1").innerHTML += items[i].get_id() + " **"+ items[i].get_item("Site")+"**";
    //window.location.href = window.location.pathname + window.location.search + window.location.hash;
    var targetListItem;

    updateListItem(myItems);
    }
}
    )
}

function updateListItem(j) {
    getItemstoUpdate().then(function(itemsToUpdate,ctx,list){
var tempi = 0;      
         var itemArray = [];
        var listItemEnumerator = itemsToUpdate.getEnumerator();
         while (listItemEnumerator.moveNext()) {
            var oItem = listItemEnumerator.get_current();
            var oListItem = list.getItemById(oItem.get_id());
            oListItem.set_item('Poka_x017c_WWidoku', 'Tak');  
            oListItem.update();
            itemArray[tempi]=oListItem;
            ctx.load( itemArray[tempi]);
             tempi++;
    }
          ctx.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQuerySucceeded), Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQueryFailed));
    })
}

function onQuerySucceeded(sender, args) {
   alert('Item Updated !!')
}

function onQueryFailed(sender, args) {

    alert('Request failed. ' + args.get_message() + '\n' + args.get_stackTrace());
}


function getSelectedItems()
{
    var dfd = $.Deferred(function () {
       var context = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
       var listId = SP.ListOperation.Selection.getSelectedList(); //get selected list Id
       var selectedItemIds = SP.ListOperation.Selection.getSelectedItems(context); //get selected objects
       var list = context.get_web().get_lists().getById(listId);
       var listItems = [];
       for (idx in selectedItemIds)
       {
          var item = list.getItemById(parseInt(selectedItemIds[idx].id));
          listItems.push(item);
          context.load(item);
       }
       context.executeQueryAsync(
         function() {
            dfd.resolve(listItems);
         },
         function (sender, args) {
               dfd.reject(args.get_message());
         }
       ); 
    });
    return dfd.promise();   
}


function getItemstoUpdate()
{
    var dfd = $.Deferred(function () {
        var siteUrl = '/sites/MCUW-IT/kostka-pilotaze/restauracje-pilotaże/';
    var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext(siteUrl);
    var oList = clientContext.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle('Testowa Lista');
        var query = new SP.CamlQuery();
               var listItems = [];
        query.set_viewXml('<View><Query><Where><Contains><FieldRef Name="Connect" /><Value Type="LookupMulti">5</Value></Contains></Where></Query></View>');
    var collListItem = oList.getItems(query);

    clientContext.load(collListItem,'Include(Id, DisplayName)');
       clientContext.executeQueryAsync(
         function() {
            dfd.resolve(collListItem,clientContext,oList);
         },
         function (sender, args) {
               dfd.reject(args.get_message());
         }
       ); 
    });
    return dfd.promise();   
}
</script>

<input id="123" onclick="abc();" type="button" value="Pokaż rekordy"/>
<div>
   <p id="p1">​​<br/></p>
</div>
```

If two items selected then item will be updated twice. Please check modify accordingly.

Comment: But in Succes i haven't seen this:
 collListItem.set_item('Poka_x017c_WWidoku', 'Tak');
    collListItem.update();
How BhaskarDhone I can use this two liness when success

Comment: Please Bhaskar Dhone look on my Edited code. I add a Iterator, but the button don't firred. Somewere there is a javascript mistake.

Comment: let me give you exact code to try

Comment: Can You Bhaskar Dhone look for code? Please

Comment: Look my edited Code

Comment: Thanks Bhasjar Dhone, but after button fired and checked first 30 nothing doing, and main point is write in column 'Poka_x017c_WWidoku' text Tak when column "Connect" contains any number of  fro  column "Site"

Comment: It don't fired after button click.

Comment: Still I have got problem with this solution.